# Trying to Extract Previous Day Azure VM Report but unable to Do via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, backup

I am trying to generate backup report for previous day via Powershell but its not working .Can anyone help me on that .
Below is my Powershell Script

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$report_object =$null
$report_object = @()
$vms = get-azvm | select Name
$acs = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault
foreach ($ac in $acs){
Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $ac
$container_list = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM
foreach($container_list_iterator in $container_list){ 
$backup_item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container_list_iterator -WorkloadType AzureVM
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing two curly braces (**}}**) at the end of the code. Is it just a typo? Or is that the reason for you to be unable to extract the report?

I have tried to reproduce the issue to see if I get any exceptions while execution but it all went well as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Can you elaborate on what you meant by "unable to extract the report". Did you receive any error while executing the code? Please provide more details in that context.